# Passing CLI args to pre-command in package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

Let's say I have in my package.json:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "some-command",
    "build": "some-other-command"
  }
}
```

If I now run `npm run build -- --some-args`, the `prebuild` command `some-command` *does not* get the `--some-args` passed to it. How can I pass this to all the pre/post scripts as well?

Comment: You can't. That's a limitation of the pre- and post- hooks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe looks like this did happen at one point? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6343

Comment: The question asks for either doing a `pre` or chaining commands using `&&`. The answer only speaks of the former.

Comment: Well you've illustrated the behaviour for yourself and found where it was taken out, it's hard to see what's still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it using environment variable:

```
"scripts": {                                                                  
    "prebuild": "echo $FLAG \"prebuild\"",                                
    "build": "echo \"testing\""                                                     
}
```

If you run `npm run build`:

```
> test@1.0.0 prebuild /test
> echo $FLAG "prebuild"

prebuild

> test@1.0.0 build /test
> echo "testing"

testing
```

And if you run `FLAG=-n npm run build`:

```
> test@1.0.0 prebuild /test
> echo $FLAG "prebuild"

prebuild
> test@1.0.0 build /test
> echo "testing"

testing
```

However I'm not sure if it will work with multiple flags

Comment: You don't need to actually do the `echo $FLAG` environment variables are passed to pre/post scripts